# Increase Session Time of MVC 3 application deploy on IIS 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, iis-6

How to increase session time out of Deployed MVC 3 Application on IIS 3

I have tried following ways.

**1. Changes on Web.config**

**2. Changes in IIS 6.0 => Asp =>session properties =>timeout 23:59:00**

But Still its not working .

Suggest any setting to increase session time out for long time.

Comment: Check below ans this is definitely work for you once done please mark this ans as accepted to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change session time in WEB config like this that is the only one way to increase session time, mine is working perfect :

```
<sessionState timeout="60" mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set timeout attribute of sessionState element (web.config).

**timeout attribute of sessionState element (web.config):**
If the user remains idle for duration specified in timeout attribute vaule of sessionState element (in web.config), then his session will expire.

timeout attribute of sessionState element (in the web.config) can be used to change session timeout duration for ASP.NET Application. timeout value is specified in minutes.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**For other timeouts check:** [How to increase timeout for your ASP.NET Application ?](http://www.techcartnow.com/increase-timeout-asp-net-application/)